# Solve for x in this equation with trig and exponential functions added together?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, arithmetic

I'm having trouble putting this equation in terms of $x$, so I figured I'd ask here:
$$y=25(x+0.5)^2+150\cos(0.5x)$$

I tried to subtract $150\cos(0.5x)$ from both sides and then divide by $25$, giving $$\frac{y-150\cos(0.5x)}{25}=(x+0.5)^2$$ and then taking the square root of both sides which gives me $$\sqrt\frac{y-150\cos(0.5x)}{25}=x+0.5,$$ and then subtracting the $0.5$. I'm stuck here, though. I'm not sure what to do with the x on the left side of the equation. This seems out of my league so if you could also explain how it was done that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to get $x$ as a function of $y$? Why do you think there is a nice analytical formula for it? Also, please use MathJax to format your questions. Mostly it involves putting `$` around your equations

Comment: @Indir Keep in mind that not all functions have a global inverse and, even if they do, you may not be able to find an explicit expression. Where you specifically asked to provide an expression for the inverse function?

Comment: @Andrei I wasn't sure if there was an expression. If not it's fine. This equation determines required experience points (y) based on level (x) so I was trying to find level based on experience points.

Comment: Probably a numeric solution is the only way